# How to traverse an object that has more Objects inside and temporarily cast the type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following code that runs through a GroupControl, natively in c # is called GroupBox, what I want to do is go through it internally and depending on the object that is I want to perform an action, for example:

```
foreach (Control item in groupControl1.Controls)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());

    if (item is CalcEdit)
    {
        (CalcEdit)item = item.value=0
    }

    if (item is DateEdit)
    {
        (DateEdit)item = item.DateTime.now
    }
}
```

But I do not know the correct way to caste the object temporarily to obtain its properties and thus establish the value I want.

What would be suggestible?

Comment: `((DesireType)item).Whatever = newValue` or `if(item is DesireType typedItem)` and then use `typedItem`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```cs
foreach (Control item in groupControl1.Controls)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());

    if (item is CalcEdit calcItem)
    {
        calcItem.Value = 0;
    }
    else if (item is DateEdit dateItem)
    {
        dateItem.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

I've made some small adjustments because your code seems to make no sense but the pattern matching is the important part.

You could also do this:

```cs
foreach (var item in groupControl1.Controls.OfType<CalcEdit>())
{
    item.Value = 0;
}

foreach (var item in groupControl1.Controls.OfType<DateEdit>())
{
    item.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

The second option is less efficient because it enumerates the entire `Controls` collection twice but the difference will be insignificant as the number of items will be so small.

Answer (score 0):

The (excellent) answer of @jmcilhinney requires C# 7.0 or later. If, for some reason, you're limited to an earlier version (which lacks pattern matching), this slightly more cumbersome approach is an alternative:

```
CalcEdit calcEditItem = item as CalcEdit;
if (calcEditItem != null)
{
    calcEditItem.Value = 0;
}

DateEdit dateEditItem = item as DateEdit;
if (dateEditItem != null)
{
    dateEditItem.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the determining the type and setting a property on it is trivial

```
var control = current as TextBox;
if (control != null) control.Text = "x"
// or
if (current is TextBox) 
{
    control = (TextBox)current;
    control.Text = "x" ;
}
// or same ^^ with use pattern matching in the later c# versions
```

But this also represents an interesting case for the implementation of "chain of responsibility" pattern, **but only** in case if you have more complex logic than just merely setting a value

```cs
public abstract class ControlHandler
{
    private ControlHandler _nextHandler;
    
    public void AddNext(IControlHandler h)
    {
        _nextHandler = h;
    }
    
    public void SetValue(Control c, object val)
    {
        if (SetValueProtected(c, val))
            return;

        if (_nextHandler != null)
            return;
    
    }

    protected abstract bool CanSetValueProtected(Control c, object val);
} 


public class TextBoxControlHandler  : ControlHandler
{
    
    protected override bool CanSetValueProtected(Control c, object val)
    {
         if (!(c is TexBox))
             return false;
         // your value and other logic here
         // AND !! you can pass form/parent control reference here to do more
         return true;
    }
} 

public class CalcEditControlHandler  : ControlHandler
{
    
    protected override bool CanSetValueProtected(Control c, object val)
    {
         if (!(c is CalcEdit))
             return false;
         // your value and other logic here
         // AND !! you can pass form/parent control reference here to do more
         return true;
    }
} 
// ------------
// USAGE

var first = new TextBoxControlHandler();
var second = new CalcEditControlHandler(); second.AddNext(first);
// more handlers here


foreach (Control item in groupControl1.Controls)
    first.SetValue(item, value);
```

But then again.. see if this is not an overkill for you